# Item is selected but isn't highlighted

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qabstractitemview

I work with Qt/C++, and I have a QListView to display icons on screen.
I set the QListView::iconMode to display it as icon view. But I cannot see that it is selected(but it is selected) it doesn't highlights. However it works for list mode.
I have this.

```
listView->setSelectionMode(QListView::SingleSelection);
listView->setSelectionBehavior(QListView::SelectRows);

listView->setFlow(QListView::LeftToRight);
listView->setViewMode(QListView::IconMode);
listView->setWrapping(true);
```

can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried calling update on the Lit view during the resize event?

Comment: qt4 or qt5? or both? choose.

Comment: doesn't matter, both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation of selection rectangle](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistview.html#selectionRectVisible-prop):

> This property holds if the selection rectangle should be visible.
>   
>  If this property is true then the selection rectangle is
>   visible; otherwise it will be hidden. 
>  Note: The selection
>   rectangle will only be visible if the selection mode is in a mode
>   where more than one item can be selected; i.e., it **will not draw** a
>   selection rectangle if the selection mode is
>   ***QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection***. 
>  **By default, this property
>   is false.**

You have to try either:

- Manually set the property to true and see if it changes
- Drop the single selection mode. It is compulsory? Does `QAbstractItemView::ContiguousSelection` suits your needs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm archeologist :D

Worked solution:

```
listView->setStyleSheet(" QListView::item:selected { border: 2px solid red; }");
```

You can use your own border.

Comment: this forbids you from using Palettes with are amazing, give them a try! [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html) are the documents;